# @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") using is it harmful?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

My code was giving an error
Overwriting this annotation fixed the error. Is this a healthy solution?
The class giving the error is related to bluetooth.

```
"Add permissions check" It gives an error when I do the suggestion.
```

Error:
Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException

Thanks

I used  @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") but I couldn't trust

```
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
        device, final String socketType) {
    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
    if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mSecureAcceptThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, socketType);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothState.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(BluetoothState.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    bundle.putString(BluetoothState.DEVICE_ADDRESS, device.getAddress());
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    setState(BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, in order for `MissingPermission` error not to appear, you would have to check for the permission within the function.

Now, if you are absolutely certain, that the permission is, and will be, getting checked **before** the call of this function, it is OK to use `@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")`. What I would additionally do, is put a comment as to why you suppressed the error. Something in the line of: `@SuppressLint("MissingPermission") // permission must be checked before the call of the function!`.

Comment: this sother solution give error for this context                                                                         if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           
            return;
        }

Comment: In order for others to understand exactly what you are doing and what the error is, edit your original answer. Write EDIT below your current text and show what you did and what the result/error was.